# Baby Rudin Theorem 3.10(b)

Tags: real-analysis

Baby Rudin Theorem 3.10(b):
If $K_n$ is a sequence of compact sets in $\boldsymbol X$ such that $K_n \supset K_{n+1}$ ($n=1,2,3,\dots$) and if
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \operatorname {diam} K_n=0
$$
then $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}K_n$ consists of exactly one point.

Do we require the sets $K_n$ to be nonempty?

Comment: Write down your theorem. Did you see the theorem 2.34? Think, if $K_n$ is empty then what happen.

Comment: Actually, I didn't see it has relation to theorem 2.34. If $K_n$ is empty for all $n \geq m$, then it still satisfies $K_n \supset K_{n+1}$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} diam K_n=0$. But $\bigcap_1^{\infty} K_n$ is empty.

Comment: if $K_n$ is empty. Then what will be the $diam$ of $K_n$? **diam=diameter**

Comment: Oh, I just forgot diameter is only defined on nonempty sets. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the **Definition 3.9.** in Baby Rudin; diameter is defined only for **non-empty** subspace of metric space. So here $K_n$ is implicitly assumed to be non-empty as we deal with $\text{diam}(K_n)$.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!